# Fortran to Python for running external files

Tags: python, fortran

To run in Fortran code, i am using the following code without problems:

```
RUNSa = SETENVQQ('PATH="C:\.......\Bin"') 
RUNSa = SYSTEM('MdoCmd.exe WW.ghz /solve:all /report:all')
```

how can i run in Python code? I tryed the following codes without successfully:

```
RUNSa = subprocess.Popen([r"C:\.......\Bin\MdoCmd.exe", r"D:\.......\WW.ghz"])
```

or

```
"C:\.......\Bin\MdoCmd.exe" "D:\.......\WW.ghz" /solve
```

Someone to help me?

Comment: Why does the `WW.ghz` have a full path added to it in the Python version? What error messages does the unsuccessful generate?

Comment: Do you want to run it as a separate process and forget about it or wait until it finishes?

Comment: It is an external software and i just try to run the software with commands in a python code. I will need to wait up to finish the process.
This errors appear: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Step1_v1.py", line 45, in <module>
"C:\.......\Bin\MdoCmd.exe" "D:\.......\WW.ghz" /solve > MdoCmd2020.out
NameError: name 'solve' is not defined
***Repl Closed***